# c++ : returning reference to temporary

Tags: c++, reference

I have made this c++ code :

```
std::string const &     Operand::toString() const
{
  std::ostringstream    convert;
  convert << this->value;
  return convert.str();
}
```

The compiler tells me : `returning reference to temporary`

Am I forced to put `convert.str()` in my `Operand` class ?

EDIT : It's for a school exercise, I can't change the prototype

Comment: Just return by-value and order will be restored.

Comment: Why are you using an ostringstream to convert values to strings? What is the type of this->value?

Comment: For the moment, it's an int, but later it will become a template variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
convert.str();
```

this returns an `std::string` object which will be destroyed after  `Operand::toString()` returns. Thus this is temporary variable with lifetime limited to scope of this function. You should return just the `string` itself, by value:

```
std::string Operand::toString() const
{
  std::ostringstream    convert;
  convert << this->value;
  return convert.str();
}
```

or:

```
const std::string Operand::toString() const
{
  std::ostringstream    convert;
  convert << this->value;
  return convert.str();
}
```

Comment: Last function will not work. It is not a member function and `this->value` does not exist as a result.. Perhaps you meant to put `value` as a parameter or make the function a member?

Comment: sure, I have added Operand::, this is a member function

Answer (score 4):

Just change the function to return a `std::string` instead of a `std::string const &`. You want to return by value here.

Comment: It's for a school exercise, I can't change the prototype

Comment: @JérémyPouyet Umm...Then assign `str()` to a static `std::string` and return that instead.

Comment: Or perhaps `Operand` should have a member string that you should be returning a const reference to.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Returning a reference to a changing string would be extremely confusing in my opinion.

Comment: @sepp2k It's quite common to return a const reference to a member variable with the agreement that the value is stable until another member function is called.

Comment: the problem is that the method is const, so you can't change the string.  you'd have to make the string mutable, i guess.  all of this will come out to be a mess.

Comment: @thang That is correct. The method is `const` because it doesn't change the logical value of the object, so the string should be `mutable`. It may be a bit less than ideal, but we have a silly constraint we can't change, so that forces our hand a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `&` and const

i.e.

```
std::string Operand::toString() const
{
  std::ostringstream    convert;
  convert << this->value;
  return convert.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the prototype - it must return reference instead the string itself - you have to keep the string somewhere and return reference to it. Maybe create a static string, assign `convert.str()` into it and return reference to this static string.

```
std::string const & Operand::toString() const
{
  static std::string s;
  std::ostringstream convert;
  convert << this->value;
  s = convert.str();
  return s;
}
```

Another solution is recommended in comment by David Schwartz (at different answer), but it depends if you can add that member string to `Operand`.

Comment: why it cannot return const string by value?

Comment: @piotruś Returning by value would be probably best solution, but, as said in question, declaration of `Operand::toString()` cannot be changed.

Comment: This will lead to very confusing behavior if the caller keeps the returned reference around and `toString` is called on multiple objects. I wouldn't recommend this at all. If a reference needs to be returned it should be a reference to a member, which at least doesn't get overridden every time `toString` is called on another object.

Comment: The caller can make a copy of the returned value.

Comment: This is a *terrible* solution because it has hidden side-effects, e.g. it's not thread-safe, it's not safe to call twice unless you remember to make a copy, and it forcibly makes a copy of the ostringstream::str object into a static object in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it is terrible solution. I would not use this myself.

Comment: This is a terrible situation except that you can use it in one circumstance: where you are looking something up and if it does not exist you return a reference to a "static" constant object, e.g. an empty string, which you create as static but always remains just empty.

That does not, of course, apply here.